# PhpStorm JS inspection - JS variable coming from backend

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, warnings, webstorm

I wanted to take some time to "clean" a personal app, to remove most of the warnings, etc.

As stated in the title I use the PhpStorm IDE and I have some warnings "Unresolved variable slug" when I use `series.slug`. The variable `series` comes from either a JSON from a PHP Class or after an Ajax call.

Is there a way to indicate an object's properties or to link a js variable to a PHP class (like in Twig)?

P.S. In my "Settings > Languages > JS > Code Quality Tools", I have nothing enabled, I just have the "basic" PhpStorm inspection.

Answer (score 1):

If you use some object with keys only known in runtime (generated, received through the ajax call, etc.) in your code, there is no way for the IDE to resolve them using static code analysis.
But you can let the IDE know what your runtime data looks like. Possible solution using JSDoc annotations:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} series
 * @property {string} slug
 * ... other series props here....
 */
...

/**
 * function that uses series data
 * @param {series} data
 */
function foo (data){...}
```

See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17419#comment=27-1058451, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206349469-disable-unresolved-variable-on-json-object-received-by-ajax-call for other possible workarounds

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look at JSDoc, but it seems it could solve the problem.